# How to use one dataframe's index to reindex another one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am so sorry that I truly don't know what title I should use. But here is my question

```
Stocks_Open
               d-1           d-2         d-3          d-4
000001.HR  1817.670960  1808.937405  1796.928768  1804.570628  
000002.ZH  4867.910878  4652.713598  4652.713598  4634.904168 
000004.HD    92.046474    92.209029    89.526880    96.435445   
000005.SS    28.822245    28.636893    28.358865    28.729569  
000006.SH   192.362963   189.174626   185.986290   187.403328   
000007.SH    79.190528    80.515892    81.509916    78.693516
```

```
Stocks_Volume
               d-1           d-2         d-3          d-4
000001.HR    324234         345345      657546       234234  
000002.ZH    4867343        465234      4652598      4634168 
000004.HD    9246474        929029      826880       965445   
000005.SS    2822245        2836893     2858865      2829569  
000006.SH    19262963       1897466    1886290      183328   
000007.SH    7190528        803892      809916       7693516
```

Above are the data I parsed from a database, what I exactly want to do is to obtain the correlation of open price and volume in 4 days for each stock (The first column consists of codes of different stocks). In other words, I am trying to calculate the correlation of corresponding rows of each DataFrame. (This is only simplified example, the real data should be extended to more than 1000 different stocks.)

My attempt is to create a dataframe and to run a loop, assigning the results to that dataframe. But here is a problem, which is, the index pf the created dataframe is not exactly what I want. When I tried to append the correlation column, the bug occurred. (Please ignore the value of correlation, which is I concocted here, just to give an example)

```
r = pd.DataFrame(index = range(6),columns = ['c']
        
        for i in range(6):
            r.iloc[i-1,:] = Stocks_Open.iloc[i-1].corr(Stocks_Volume.iloc[i-1])

        Correlation_in_4days = pd.concat([Stocks_Open,Stocks_Volume], axis = 1)
        Correlation_in_4days['corr'] = r['c']
        for i in range(6):
            Correlation_in_4days.iloc[i-1,8] = r.iloc[i-1,:]


r     c
1   0.654  
2  -0.454
3   0.3321   
4   0.2166   
5   -0.8772   
6    0.3256
```

The bug occurred.

```
"ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series"
```

I realized that my correlation dataframe's index is integer but not the stock code, but I don't know how to fix it, is there any help?
My ideal result is:

```
             corr 
000001.HR    0.654
000002.ZH    -0.454
000004.HD    0.3321  
000005.SS    0.2166
000006.SH    -0.8772
000007.SH    0.3256
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assign the `index` back

```
r.index = Stocks_Open.index
```